# Nifi run batch file. CMD (.bat). ExecuteProcess

Tags: batch-file, cmd, apache-nifi

I have tried several configurations to run batch script (cmd) in Windows following a schedule using nifi. I think this configuration should work using ExecuteProcess processor. But it does not.

My "ExecuteProcess" configuration is:

- Command: `cmd`
- Command arguments: `C:\Users\SA-2J04-SAFES\Desktop\sync.bat`

My .bat script is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://exchange:Illescas.exchange@30.208.6.43/ -hostkey=""ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 384 T8cTR+P5Ubm9NrbrcopI2mSz2QUOzYRvQrS1w+rSoyM=""" ^
    "synchronize local -delete \\SFS.CORP\Apps\ICT\ZILOC\intercambiosSFTP\SPC /" ^
    "exit"
```

If I run ".bat" file outside nifi it works fine.

Could someone help me? I have googled without results.

Would it be possible to include url and folder paths as variables/parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the help information for the command `cmd`. Open a Command Prompt window, type `cmd /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read it. Please also note that a `.bat` file can run without specifically sending it as an argument to `cmd.exe`, although when it is, that happens in the background.

Comment: NiFi has some great support channels using email lists and a Slack Channel.  I would highly advise you use those two forms of support.  It has always helped me. You can find links to that support [here](https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `/C` switch for `cmd`.

This does not work:

```
cmd C:\Users\SA-2J04-SAFES\Desktop\sync.bat
```

You need to use

```
cmd /C C:\Users\SA-2J04-SAFES\Desktop\sync.bat
```

So you need to prepend the `/C` before your "Command arguments".